# Why is my Terraria house not valid?

Tags: terraria

[image]

It says this is not valid housing when i'm pretty sure it is. this is 1.2. is the floor too high up?

Comment: Wooden platforms don't work for housing. You need to use actual wood blocks.

Comment: @Fluttershy wooden platforms are allowed, just not all of the floor.

Answer (score 3):

Every house needs at least some tiles of non-wood platforms in the floor.

Replace the three platforms under the chair and table with wood and the housing will be valid.

Comment: @Seanorrhea since the answer sounds like it works could you mark it as accepted?  Thanks.